# ThemeKey rule; how to target IMCE pages

Tags: files, theme-negotiation

On my Drupal 7 site, I noticed that the [IMCE](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce) popup loses its action buttons and all functionality when I'm using [Adminimal](https://www.drupal.org/project/adminimal_theme) as the admin theme:

[image: Where are the buttons?]

In the *Known Issues* section of the IMCE project page, it mentions using the [ThemeKey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey) module if there is a conflict with your custom theme. Here are the ThemeKey rules it says to write:

```
drupal:path = %token
drupal:path:wildcard token * imce
```

When I do this, the IMCE buttons are, in fact, back in place (yay!)... *BUT* the entire site, both public pages and administration pages, are also displayed in Garland (boo!).

How can I force *just* the IMCE popup window to render in Garland?

Answer (score 0):

As is my nature, I was totally overthinking this. Here's what I had to do in ThemeKey:

First, for the File field:

```
drupal:path = imce-filefield/%
```

Basically, this is matching the first section of the URL path with `imce-filefield` and then whatever else comes after it is matched with `/%`.

This solves the problem for file/image uploads. The IMCE file browser used in the WYSIWYG editor (in my case, [CKEditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor)) has a different URL path, so its interface is still broken. That one is simply:

```
drupal:path = imce
```

So far so good...